# How to get SharePoint taxonomy terms programmatically using JSOM?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Sometimes there is a requirement to fetch the SharePoint taxonomy term sets programmatically. So, how to get SharePoint taxonomy terms programmatically using JSOM ?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a way to fetch SharePoint taxonomy terms using JavaScript code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
SP.SOD.registerSod('sp.taxonomy.js', "/_layouts/15/sp.taxonomy.js");
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.taxonomy.js', false, Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
var termStore = taxonomySession.get_termStores().getByName("Taxonomy_qeFlDdEX32yZ3Q7EpEIeMQ==");
var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("ed6d3beb-6a49-4444-bc5d-456f747e139d");
var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();
context.load(terms);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
var termsEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
var menuItems = new Array();
while (termsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
var currentTerm = termsEnumerator.get_current();
var targetGroups = document.getElementById("selectTaxonomy");
var taxoGroup = document.createElement("option");
taxoGroup.text = currentTerm.get_name();
targetGroups.add(taxoGroup);
}
}), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
alert('The error has occured: ' + args.get_message());
}));
}));
},"sp.js")
});
```